# Python-pandas: the truth value of a series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to compare values from a json file(on which I can already work on) to values from a csv file(which might be the issue). My current code looks like this:

```
for data in trades['timestamp']:
    data = pd.to_datetime(data)
    print(data)
       if data == ask_minute['lastUpdated']:
           #....'do something'
```

Which gives:

> ":The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

My current `print(data)` looks like this:

```
2018-10-03 18:03:38.067000
2018-10-03 18:03:38.109000
2018-10-03 18:04:28
2018-10-03 18:04:28.685000
```

However, I am still unable to compare these timestamps from my CSV file to those of my Json file. Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let's reduce it to a simpler example. By doing for instance the following comparison:

```
3 == pd.Series([3,2,4,1])

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

The result you get is a `Series` of booleans, equal in size to the `pd.Series` in the right hand side of the expression. So really what's happening here is that the integer is being *broadcast* across the series, and then they are compared. So when you do:

```
if 3 == pd.Series([3,2,4,1]):
    pass
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

You get an error. The problem here is that you are comparing a `pd.Series` with a value, so you'll have multiple `True` and multiple `False` values, as in the case above. This of course is *ambiguous*, since the condition is neither `True` or `False`.

So you need to further aggregate the result so that a single *boolean* value results from the operation. For that you'll have to use either [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) or [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) depending on whether you want at least one (`any`) or `all` values to satisfy the condition.

```
(3 == pd.Series([3,2,4,1])).all()
# False
```

or

```
(3 == pd.Series([3,2,4,1])).any()
# True
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem I see is that even if you are evaluating one row in a dataframe, the code knows that a dataframe has the ability to have many rows. The code doesn't just assume you want the only row that exists. You have to tell it explicitly. The way I solved it was like this:

```
if data.iloc[0] == ask_minute['lastUpdated']:
```

then the code knows you are selecting the one row that exists.

Comment: Your answer should be given as a code. You can use the editor or the backticks to highlight the code.