# Trying to create a predetermined answer from conditions relating to 2 other columns within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Year", "Fuel", "Status", "Sex", "Service", "Expected"])
```

The other columns contain data created using `np.random`.

Within the "expected" column I would like to input Pass or Fail depending on a few conditions. If the mileage is less 100000 and if the service is yes then it will pass, otherwise its a fail.

This is what I have so far

```
df["Expected"]  = df.loc[(df['Mileage']< 100000) | (df['Service'] == 'Yes', "Pass", "Fail")]
```

It is bringing up the error message

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (500,) (3,)
```

I have filled the other columns with 500 lines of data. But I am not sure what the 3 relates to. Possibly the Yes, Pass, Fail values.

I also tried `df['Expected'] = np.where(df ["Mileage"] < 132352, ['Service'] == "Yes",'Pass','Fail')`  which kind of worked.

Am I on the wrong track?

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a function that takes a `pd.Series` object as the only argument, and then returns the value for that cell. Then use `pd.apply(lambda row: your_function(row), axis=1)`. So:

```py
def your_function(row):
    if row["Mileage"] <132352 and row["Service"] == "Yes" :# fill in your other conditions here
        return "Pass"
    else:
        return "Fail"

df["Expected"] = df.apply(lambda row: your_function(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: At the last line pd.apply creates the" AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'apply"' so I changed it to df.apply which then creates "ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 1')".  I then used                                                                                                   `def fun(row):
    if row["Mileage"] <100000 and df['Service'].any():
        return "Pass"
    else:
        return "Fail"

df["Expected"] = df.apply(lambda row: fun(row), axis=1)`  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, sorry. it should be `df.apply`. I'm confused on what you are doing with the `.any()`. Could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: would it make sense to do `df["service"] = "Yes"`

Comment: If I use just `def fun(row):
    if row["Mileage"] <100000 and df['Service']:`  I get the error message ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 2').  So I put in  .any(): after   I looked up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53830081/python-pandas-the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous and came across You are comparing two pd.Series, or a pd.Series with a value, so you might have multiple True and multiple False values, you have to do instead:if (data == ask_minute['lastUpdated']).any()

Comment: oh, sorry. Use `row["Service"]`. `row` in your function is a pd.Series of one row of your df.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for all the time you put into this.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply fill the `Expected` column with `'Fail'`:

```
df['Expected'] = 'Fail'
```

And then:

```
df.at[df[(df['Mileage']<100000) & (df['Service'] == 'Yes')].index,'Expected'] = 'Pass'
```

Comment: Returns Fail for every cell.

Comment: Are you sure there are rows in your dataframe that fills the requirements? This should work just fine.

Comment: Yes. Im looking at one that has 43000 and Yes for a service but its still a fail.

Comment: I have managed to find the error in my code. It should work now.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for taking the time to go through this.