# If statement is not working due to truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, if-statement, mean

I have got the value of mean that is .0004 from the program given below.

```
dff = pd.read_csv("I01.csv")
avg = dff['A'].rolling(3).mean()
dff['I_mean'] = avg
window = []
listpos = 0 
for datapoint in dff.A:
    mean = dff.I_mean[listpos] 
    print(mean)
    if (datapoint < mean) and (len(window) < 1):
        listpos += 1
```

After simulation the program if statement is not working.
It shows error.

```
  A    0.0004
  dtype: float64

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-49a6c73fdd23> in <module>()
     74     mean = dff.I_mean[listpos] 
     75     print(mean)
---> 76     if (datapoint < mean) & (len(window) < 1):
     77         listpos += 1

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1328     def __nonzero__(self):
   1329         raise ValueError(
-> 1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1331             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1332         )


ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

.0004 is the mean value. If I put this mean value (.0004) directly on the code then my program shows no error. Why it's happening? What's wrong in the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: Also, posting a full traceback is a good idea.

Comment: This also might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53830081/python-pandas-the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous

Comment: What happens if after `print(mean)` you put `print(type(datapoint))`? Are you comparing a series to a single value?

Comment: I don't have your CSV so I cannot replicate your issue. You probably should provide a [mcve].

Comment: This is minimal reproducible example. The actual program is too long.

Comment: How is it reproducible if I don't have the CSV?

Comment: @GregSchmit the output of print(type (datapoint)) is dtype: float64
<class 'float'>

Comment: @GregSchmit   CSV data has 3000 entries. Should I update a few data here?

Comment: Right now this example isn't reproducible, nor is it minimal. Rather than complicate it with a CSV, produce an example which uses some static data, like `dff = pd.Series([1,2,3])` (or whatever) and try to replicate your error. I suspect that in that process you'll figure out what is wrong. Perhaps the old wording will help: I need a **minimal**, **complete**, and **verifiable** example in order to help you.

Comment: Put another way: right now when I paste your code into a Python file, it doesn't run. Make it minimal and complete so I can run it on my system.