# Python Error: Truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, series, ambiguous

I am having an error: `Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()` I understood the context of this error but I am unable to fix this. Here `ps` is the list of either `float` or `NnN` that's it. In this case what it has caused it to be ambiguous to handle if statement?
It gives an error on line 3, 5, 9 and lastly at sort statement.

```
               for item in candidates:
                    print("I am candidate loop \n",item)
                    ps=2*tmp3[0,i]/((diagonal.loc[x1])["pc"]+(diagonal.loc[item+1])["pc"])
                    print(ps)
                    if ps > 0:
                        if len(out)<k:
                            out.append([ps, item+1])
                        else:
                            if ps > min(out,key=lambda x:x[0])[0]):
                                out.remove(min(out,key=lambda x:x[0]))
                                out.append([ps,item+1])
                    else:
                        pass
                    i+=1
    
                out.sort()
                out.reverse()
```

I follwed this solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53830081/python-pandas-the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous) platform also tried this way just in case if all values are greater then `zero` The if loop continues but then it gives the same error on `out.sort()`.

```
for item in candidates:
                    print("I am candidate loop \n",item)
                    ps=2*tmp3[0,i]/((diagonal.loc[x1])["pc"]+(diagonal.loc[item+1])["pc"])
                    print(ps)
                    if (ps > 0).all():
                        if len(out)<k:
                            out.append([ps, item+1])
                        else:
                            if (ps > min(out,key=lambda x:x[0])[0]).all():
                                out.remove(min(out,key=lambda x:x[0]))
                                out.append([ps,item+1])
                    else:
                        pass
                    i+=1
    
                out.sort()
                out.reverse()
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To find where the exception arises, you could step through the program in a debugger such as the PyCharm debugger. Then you can make a minimal test case to request help on if you're still stuck. Are you working with a list or a numpy array?

Comment: Alright i will try to and I am working with numpy array. `ps` should only contain the result of  `ps=2*tmp3[0,i]/((diagonal.loc[x1])["pc"]+(diagonal.loc[item+1])["pc"])` before `if` statement but it fails to calculate the `ps` for all candidate list.