# Doing a loop calculation

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, logical-operators

toto =

| C1Date | C1Type | C2Date | C2Type | ..... | C10Date | CType10 | PolDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dd-mm-yyyy | :Proposer | NaT | NaN |  | NaT | NaN | dd-mm-yyyy |
| dd-mm-yyyy | :Proposer | NaT | NaN |  | NaT | NaN | dd-mm-yyyy |
| dd-mm-yyyy | :Other | dd-mm-yyyy | Proposer |  | NaT | NaN | dd-mm-yyyy |
| dd-mm-yyyy | :Proposer | NaT | NaN |  | NaT | NaN | dd-mm-yyyy |
| dd-mm-yyyy | :Other | dd-mm-yyyy | Other |  | NaT | NaN | dd-mm-yyyy |

where `C` refers to `Claim`
and so on. i.e there is upto 10 `Claims` on a row.

I need to identify if any of the `Claims` is from the `Proposer` and for those claims did they occur within 3 years from the `PolDate` (`PolDate` is always greater than any `Cdate`)

I was able to do the following but I cannot get the date subtraction to work within the loop:

```py
CLM = {}

for i in range(1 , 11):
    

    CLM[i] = toto.loc[toto[f'C{i}Type'] == 'Proposer']
    
    #can't get this date subtraction to work within the loop. But can do the subtraction outside of the loop.

    CLM[i]['diff'] = (CLM[i]['PolDate'].sub(CLM[i][f'C{i}Date'], 
    axis=0)).dt.days
   
    use_cols = ['CustomerID',  f'C{i}Type', f'C{1}Date', 'PolDate  ']
    CLM[i] = CLM[i][use_cols]
    
    print("Claim:" + f'{i}' +" "+ str(CLM[i].shape))
```

ERROR:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
> using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Also, cannot get the 3-year comparison to work:

```
if (CLM[1]['diff'] > 1095): 
    #1095 = (365 * 3):
    CLM[1]['CLMLAST3'] = 0
else:
    CLM[1]['diff'] = 1
```

ERROR:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: You will find data analysis easier when you use tidy data https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, try this, it works for me: (Don't know much pandas so maybe efficiency is your domain, I just removed the errors from the posted code)

```
CLM = {}

for i in range(1 , 11):
    

    CLM[i] = toto.loc[toto[f'C{i}Type'] == 'Proposer']
    
    #can't get this date subtraction to work within the loop. But can do the subtraction outside of the loop.

    **CLM.get(i).loc[:, 'diff'] = (pd.to_datetime(CLM[i]['PolDate'],format='%d-%m-%Y').sub(pd.to_datetime(CLM[i][f'C{i}Date'],format='%d-%m-%Y'))).dt.days**
   
    use_cols = ['CustomerID',  f'C{i}Type', f'C{1}Date', 'PolDate  ']
    CLM[i] = CLM[i][use_cols]
    
    print("Claim:" + f'{i}' +" "+ str(CLM[i].shape))
```

Points to note:

1. The warning "*A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead*" is also there in this code too. Because CLM[i]['diff'] is different from CLM[i].loc['diff']. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/5772008
2. CLM[i]['PolDate'] is a "list" of strings, so you don't subtract a string from a string, but you can subtract a pandas datetime object from another. So, converted them first to a datetime object, then subtracted.

Same is with your extra question where you compare a list with a value, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53830333/5772008
In short, you most probably want this: "if (CLM[1]['diff'].all() > 1095)", so it compares every value in the series, not the whole series with one value.

Comment: I'd like to get rid of the warning. i'm using an import step before: pd.read_csv( 'xxx.csv', index_col = 0, dtype{"C1Type" : "string", ... , }, parse_dates = ["CDate1", ..., "CDate10", "PolDate"])   (which i thought would tidy the data). the dtype for the dates came back as '<M8[ns]'. but i still couldn't subtract dates (can with your revised code). Many thanks, and  ' .any()' that is useful i hadnt seen that before.